# Prove $x^{4}-x+1=0$ has no solution

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

> I would like to prove that the following equation has no solution in $\mathbb{R}$
>    $$x^{4}-x+1=0$$
>
> my question : could we use  Intermediate Value Theorem to prove it otherways I'm interested in more ways of prove that has no solution in $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> without :
>
> i know that we can prove it by that way :
>
> $x=x^4+1\geq 1$ and $x^4-x+1=x^2(x^2-1)+x^2-x+1>0$

Comment: And how do you wish to use the Intermediate Value Theorem?

Comment: that what i'm looking for

Comment: The IVT is sometimes invoked to show there is a real solution by demonstrating a continuous function on a particular interval is somewhere positive and somewhere nonpositive; in this sense, your last note [the function is always positive] is in a similar spirit, though an appeal to the IVT isn't quite sensible...

Comment: I don't think proving that it has *no* solution is possible by using the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman  good explication

Comment: If you want to use calculus, find where the function attains a min, compute the min value, and find it is positive.

Comment: @AndréNicolas so i have to study the function to find the min in this case i have derived it twice am wrong

Comment: The derivative is $4x^3-1$, which is $0$ at $x=1/\sqrt[3]{4}$. Compute the function value there. You barely have to compute, since $x\lt 1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas  $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{4}}\right)^4-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{4}}+1=\frac{-3+4\cdot \sqrt[3]{4}}{4\cdot \sqrt[3]{4}}=\mathrm{Decimal:\quad }\:0.52753$

Comment: I know this is a simple approach, but why not graphing the functions $y=x^4$ and $y=x-1$ in the same xy plane. They have no point of intersection and that is quite obvious since you only have to consider $x>1$

Answer (score 11):

$$
x^4-x+1=(x^2-\tfrac12)^2+x^2-x+\tfrac34=(x^2-\tfrac12)^2+(x-\tfrac12)^2+\tfrac12
$$
is never smaller than $1/2$ and can thus have no real roots.

Answer (score 4):

This function has an absolute minimum, attained at $\dfrac{\sqrt[3]2}2$, and this minimum is positive.

Answer (score 4):

If $x = x^{4}+1$, then certainly $x \geq 1$ as $x^{4} \geq 0$ for all real $x$. But then $x^{4}  = x^{3}x \geq x$ and $x^{4}+1 \geq x+1 > x$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

Just another way, using AM-GM inequality:
$$x^4+\frac13+\frac13+\frac13\geqslant \frac4{\sqrt[4]{27}}|x|\geqslant x$$
As both inequalities cannot simultaneously be satisfied, the inequality $x^4+1> x$ is strict.

Answer (score 1):

Using analytical method  we have:
$$
y=x^4-x+1 \qquad  y'=4x^3-1 \qquad y''=12x^2
$$
si we have a stationary point for $x=\sqrt[3]{1/4}$ that is a minimum since $y'' $ is always positive.

We see that
$$
y(\sqrt[3]{1/4})=1-\frac{3}{4}\sqrt[3]{1/4} >0
$$
so, since $y$ is a continuous function $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have  $y(x)> 0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, and the function has no zeros.

A general way to find if a polynomial function has real roots, without using analysis and that can be applied in any case, is using the [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem). Note that this method can be applied in any case, without searching the roots, i.e. without really solving the polynomial equation,  but it can be extremely laborious .

Comment: would u explain how we can use sturm's theorem in that case please

Comment: As you can see in the link: ''Sturm's theorem expresses the number of distinct real roots of p located in an interval in terms of the number of changes of signs of the values of the Sturm's sequence at the bounds of the interval. Applied to the interval of all the real numbers ( from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$), it gives the total number of real roots of p.'' So, if this number is $0$ we are sure that the polynomial has no real roots.

Comment: The effective calculus of the Sturm's sequence  is really tiring. I've mentioned here this method also for general purpose ( and because you say that you are interested to other methods)  since it can be applied, in principle, also if the solution of the equation $y'(x)=0$ is as difficult as the solution of $y(x)=0$. In your case the equation $y'(x)=0$ has a simple solution, but in general it can be also difficult to solve, especially if the starting polynomial is of degree $\>4$.

Comment: @ thank u that's good explantion